# What is the encryption of the data i receive from google drive api v3 media=alt?

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I need a little help with google drive api v3 with NodeJS.
The problem I encountered:
I can download any file, but I think the encryption might be wrong.

```
 async downloadFile(fileId, mimeType) {
    await this.getToken()
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
         await axios({
              url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId,
              method: "GET",
              headers: {
                authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
              },
              params: {
                alt: 'media',
              }
            })
            .then((response) => {
     
              resolve(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        })
  }
```

And after this:

```
 let file = await drive.downloadFile(driveId, mimeType)
 fs.writeFile('./sth.jpg', data, () => {})
```

[image]
[image]

I added two pictures. First one I downloaded from the drive and the second is downloaded by my backend.

What can be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
 await axios({
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId,
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
      },
      params: {
        alt: 'media',
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {

      resolve(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

#### To:

```
await axios({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId,
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
  },
  params: {
    alt: 'media',
  },
  responseType: "arraybuffer",
})
  .then((response) => {
    resolve(new Buffer.from(response.data));
  })
  .catch((error) => reject(error));
```

- In this modification, the response type of `arraybuffer` is used.
- By this modification, the returned value of `data` can be used as `fs.writeFile("./sth.jpg", data, () => {});`.

#### Reference:

- [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)